# Installing a WP theme ive made locally to a web server

Tags: php, wordpress

**Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/content/82/6985782/html/wordpress/wp-content/themes/syntax/themeoptions.php:289) in /home/content/82/6985782/html/wordpress/wp-content/themes/syntax/themeoptions.php on line 136**

Thats the error i get whenever i want to submit something in the admin panel.

Here's the code for the themeoptions.php:

http://pastebin.com/aFWHjEv0

It all works perfectly normal on localhost, any explanations??

Comment: Do you have output buffering enabled on your local server? On your web server?

Comment: whats that? this is for wordpress. Not sure what you are referring to.

Comment: local: ; output_buffering
;   Default Value: Off
;   Development Value: 4096
;   Production Value: 4096

Comment: as for the hosting, no idea how to find out, I'm using godaddy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably `output_buffering` that is enabled on your local machine, but not on the remote server. (You can find out by using `phpinfo`).

The easy fix is to prepend your script with a output_buffering command:

```
<?php
ob_start();
```

Even better is finding out where the output starts and fix it there.

Comment: How do i go about implimenting this? where would i put it?